# List of methods associated with specific event listeners?

Tags: java, eclipse, events, listeners, event-listener

Im working on some beginner stuff in java and Im using MouseMotionListener to get input from the mouse in one of my classes. I know of the ones required already (mouseDragged, mouseMoved, etc...)

I was wondering if there was a list somewhere in eclipse or outside of eclipse where I can see all the methods associated with event listeners.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Java API Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) contains a full list.  You should bookmark the [main page of the API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) and refer to it often.  A full list of the AWT listener interfaces can be found in the [package page for java.awt.event in the API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/event/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thanks a ton! This opened up a whole plethora of answers for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of a listener interface (e.g. `MouseListener`), you can look at the source for that class. One way to do that is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the **Open Type** dialog box, then type the name of the interface, and press **OK** to view its source.

Once you've opened the source for the class, you can use the built-in Javadoc viewer (Window → Show View → Javadoc) to view the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse you could just create a new class with the wizard when needed and specify which listener interfaces it implements, Eclipse will add the method stubs by itself without any worry.

In any case the best friend is your memory and a bookmark to the API doc..